# how to put a js on the top level domain in django

Tags: python, django

I am implementing onesingal push notification on my website by reading there documentation [OneSignal WebPush notification](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/web-push-sdk-setup-https). There they say that put the corresponding javascript on the top level domain ?
In django all files are located through the route so how i should put a js on the top domain level?

eg

- https://yoursite.com/manifest.json
- https://yoursite.com/OneSignalSDKWorker.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django does not recommend serving static files through a view. So you should use nginx or apache to do it for you. It's quite easy to setup both for serving such files.

Nginx example (not tested) -

```
location (OneSignalSDKWorker.js|manifest.json) {
    root /path/to/files/directory;
}
```

If you have to do it in Django, you could add the following to your main `urls.py` -

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path(
        "manifest.json",
        TemplateView.as_view(
            template_name="path/to/manifest.json",
            content_type="application/json"
        ),
        name="manifest.json",
    ),
    path(
        "OneSignalSDKWorker.js",
        TemplateView.as_view(
            template_name="path/to/OneSignalSDKWorker.js",
            content_type="application/javascript"
        ),
        name="OneSignalSDKWorker.js",
    ),
    ...
]
```

Comment: so means we cannot do it using ? django!!

Comment: so that means i have to do using apache ??

Comment: Yes, if your django app is being served using apache.

Answer (score 0):

So the docs says that

> Upload the files to the top-level root of your site directory. The following URLs should be publicly accessible:

If you running your server in debug mode you can add route to your public static folder(it's better to have two separate folders: for basic static, and for static such as that scripts and 500.html/404.html files). w

So you need to have two separate urlpatterns.

And in production serving static should be stored though http server(such as Nginx)